# How to choose a correct LED PWM driver?

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm, driver

I would like to control an RGB LED via a (vendor specific) microcontroller. However its maximum output current is 60mA whereas my LED requires 100mA.
I have seen number of LED driver solutions with PWM support where the modulation is controlled by analogue input 0-VDD. However, I would like to use my already modulated signal from my MCU as I don't have 3 analogue output pins and MCU offers nice PWM tools.

What would be the easiest solution for me to provide the LED with the necessary 100mA while still using MCU modulated voltage signals?

Comment: A low-side driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a transistor driver for each input (LED):

[image]

Source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_8.html)

In your case the second circuit suits ([low-side driver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110474/how-to-choose-a-correct-led-pwm-driver#comment219934_110474) or current sink) and \$I_R = 100mA\$.